# How can i add a self created jar say jarFile.jar to pom.xml

Tags: maven, dependency-injection

i have created a jar with name jarFile.jar, as you can see i haven't mentioned any version of the jar which is creating problem while i trying to add this jar to pom.xml without changing the name of the jar

```
   `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>jarFile</artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </dependency>`
```

Comment: So whts the issue? You need to add version.

Comment: i need permanent solution to fixed it, if adding version is required then please guide me to do so

Comment: To be able to add your jar as a Maven dependency like in your question the jar itself must be a Maven artefact (e.g. the build result of a Maven project with packaging type jar). This way you can `mvn clean install` it into your local Maven repository to be included as dependency by other (local) Maven projects.

Note there is the possibillity to include non-Maven-Jars too (i dont know what exactly you want to archive). When it comes to Maven i recomend taking a day off and read the manual (its stunning how much of an Maven-Expert you get compared to the average Maven user by just reading it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify version, maven can't know which jar to take.
Specify the version of the jar you installed.

The procedure to install a jar i use is:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=awesomeJar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dfile=C:\myJar.jar
```

(for external jars)

or

```
mvn clean install -o
```

from the project folder for installing my own dependency jars.
I don't see the real question here.